# Ruby - undefined local variable or method `_1'

Tags: ruby

I'm getting the error `undefined local variable or method '_1' for main:Object` when I run the  following code. Any idea why I'm getting this error? and how can I store the result in a variable.

```
result="-e hostname=webserver001 -e username=root -e password=testing123"

p result.scan(/\w+=\w+/)
        .map { _1.split("=") }
        .to_h
```

`Error:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from main.rb:4:in `<main>'
    1: from main.rb:4:in `map'
main.rb:4:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `_1' for main:Object (NameError)
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably running an older version of ruby - the numbered parameters for blocks have been available in ruby since 2.7 - see https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-7-introduces-numbered-parameters-as-default-block-parameters

You can make it work on older version by using

```
p result.scan(/\w+=\w+/)
        .map { |s| s.split("=") }
        .to_h
```